# In Opera 11, how can I set up shortcuts to switch to specific tabs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, opera, browser-tabs, switching

In Firefox on Linux, we can use Alt+1, Alt+2, etc. to switch to the first, second, etc. tabs, till the 9th tab. This is *very* useful to switch between tabs. In Opera 11 on Linux, I couldn't find a way to do this: the only way to switch among tabs seems to be to use Ctrl+Tab and then cycle till we reach the tab that we want. Needless to say, this "linear access" method is slower (and more annoying) than the random access available in FF. So my question is:

> How can I set up shortcuts in Opera 11 on Linux so that I can switch to one of the first nine tabs using a numbered shortcut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way, at least it's not listed on their [shortcuts page](http://help.opera.com/Linux/11.01/en/keyboard.html) and I didn't find a way to do it.  Though you can customize shortcuts, you can't add new actions and there aren't any actions for visiting tabs 1-9.  I customized Opera to use Ctrl-PageUp/PageDown to go to the previous/next tab, but it's not as fast as going directly to a tab.

Comment: @DahH : Yeah, this is one of the two things that limits my usage of Opera ( the other being poor support for my native language ).

Comment: @gphilip I tried to use it as my primary browser, but it had a few too many quirks.  I still keep track of their updates and am hopeful :)

Answer (score 7):

Well here's the right [answer](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/go-to-a-specific-tab-using-keyboard-shortcut-in-opera); we're lucky, it came out on june 1st. Also, here is the list of all of [Opera's Actions](http://operawiki.info/AllActions) commands, but i could'nt  figure that one out...

Preferences (Ctrl+F12) > Advanced tab > Shortcuts > Edit {a duplicate of Opera Standard preferably} > Application > New... > {choose shortcut like: w alt} > Actions :: Show popup menu, "Internal Window List"

Opera users should have these two sites bookmarked.

Comment: what? enable menu, so that you could press Alt+w to open the Window menu and then press 1-9 to select the open tab?!  that would even be fine if you didn't have to show the menu bar for it to work. the other way didn't worked for opera 11.62

Comment: Links are dead (as of 4/14)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for to cycle through tabs without highlighting like that of Firefox at  http://yawar.blogspot.com/2008/04/tabbing-in-opera-and-notepad.html. Hope you'll find it useful if you like the Firefox way of tab cycling.

On the same note, I'm just realizing how customizable Opera browser really is after coming back from Firefox after years. You may want to checkout this user's tips and tweaks : http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/

Comment: Thank you, but this is _not_ what I asked. The first link only tells how to map the "cycle pages/tabs" operation to a different key than the default, while my question was about "jumping" to tab 1 .. 9 : essentially, random access instead of linear/cyclical access.

Comment: @gphilip : I'm sorry I misread the original question. I posted in a hurry because I was looking got the Ctrl + PageUp/Down tab cycling in Opera without highlighted tabs like that of Firefox and found the perfect solution that came in google along with this question. There really doesn't seem to be anyway to do this, which would be rather neat.