# How do Opera 11's keyboard shortcut settings work?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, opera

Firefox 4 beta is starting to freeze up the way Firefox 3 used to on my machine, and I want a browser that'll play gifs at full speed, so on a Mac my only other choice seems to be Opera. There are just two issues I have with it right now: one, the scrolling is weird compared to every other Mac application, but I can get used to that if there's no way to fix it. Two, cmd-1 through cmd-9 activate the "speed dial" bookmarks instead of selecting tabs 1-9, like in Firefox and Chrome.

I can disable those shortcuts easily enough, so I don't keep accidentally loading a different page when I instinctively try to do that, but in an ideal world I could remap those commands to do what I want. The keyboard shortcut editor is weird:

[image: Edit Keyboard Setup]

There seems to be a scrappy little language for associating actions with commands. It has some limited autocompletion when you type stuff in, and I couldn't find a "select specific tab" action, but some of the existing commands are complicated enough that I'd be surprised if there's not a way to do it. Is there documentation for this language anywhere? Clicking "help" just brings me to [this page](http://help.opera.com/Mac/11.01/en/input.html), which is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I voted up Shadow2531's answer for your general question, but for the specific feature you are requesting - selecting tabs 1-9 - here's a [good answer](https://superuser.com/questions/233536/in-opera-11-how-can-i-set-up-shortcuts-to-switch-to-specific-tabs/294540#294540) ( -mine, !o!)

As for Opera's "scrappy little language" you are quite right that it would need an updated, centralized, easily accessible knowledge base... Meanwhile you may also search Tamil's [resourceful blog](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/go-to-a-specific-tab-using-keyboard-shortcut-in-opera) about Opera.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer here and there. I've stopped using Opera since Chrome fixed their gif speed, though.

Answer (score 2):

Look at ui/standard_menu.ini in Opera's program files directory. That should help you learn the format easier.

Also, see the [Opera Wiki page for this](http://operawiki.info/EditingINIFiles) and all the links it points to. That will help a lot.

Opera also supports:

```
Delay, n
```

now where 'n' is the number of milliseconds. Here is an [example use case](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/findpost.pl?id=9174542).

Commands can be combined with & (for doing multiple things) or | (for toggling).

If you need more help, asking in the [customization forum](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/forum.dml?id=28) will probably help.

Comment: Indeed one needs to apply delays in order for the previous action to complete. Here :: View address bar, 2 & Delay, 222 & Focus address field & Delay, 45000 & View address bar, 0 :: the first delay is needed while the second one auto-hides the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

I found something in the opera knowledge base, there seems to be some documentation about this in the opera knowledge base [Link](http://www.opera.com/features/keyboard/index.dml?platform=mac). The link does not work for me. Since I'm a PC user, I don't know if the page format is mac specific. In advance, I found another page about opera shortcuts there [Link](http://de.opera.com/support/kb/view/272/).

Comment: your first link is giving me a 404

Comment: Like me, I'm sorry for that, it seems the article is missing in the knowledge base. I found that by going to http://opera.com/support/kb/search/ and typing "keyboard" into the search field. The first article appearing on the list seems to be what you are looking for, but the It gave me the 404.

Comment: ah, I see. the search result also mentions that it applies up to opera 9.something, while i'm using opera 11. i think their kb search might just be awful.